# Adding a modal div freezes the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an application that uses angular and bootstrap 3.  I found that if I add this line anywhere in the page, the entire application freezes - no links, form fields, etc respond to clicks on the page.  This happens in both IE and Chrome, and no errors are displayed in F12.

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce this on a smaller scale; the basic example of a modal dialog from the bootstrap site works.  Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

It turned out the cause was the following code in one of our shared libraries:

```
.modal {
  display: block;
}
```

Removing this solved the problem.  Thanks all for reading!

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you showed more code.  Or better yet, use http://www.bootply.com to show the problem with a small code sample, then link to it here.

Comment: I tried reproducing but couldn't - see my edit above as the issue was traced to code in a shared CSS file which was loaded after bootstrap.